# Ignore file during git merge. i.e. file exists on branch A but does not exist on branch B. Keep it that way when merging A->B

Tags: git, github, confluence

I have a technical documentation repo that covers general topics, let's call it 'RepoA'. I want to merge it with or "add it to" another notes repo that are specific to my job envirnment, let's call it "RepoB". The purpose is for employees to have a "one stop shop" for SOP's and more general things such as Linux , Ansible, Yum, or other topics.

So general notes would be added to RepoA , job-specific notes would be added to RepoB.  RepoB would merge with RepoA so that it has everything in RepoA plus the job-specific notes unique to RepoB.

Would it work to Make RepoA the upstream repo for RepoB , and use git fetch/git merge to add content from RepoA to RepoB ?

```
e.g. repob(master)> git remote add repoa repoa_url 
repob(master)>git fetch repoa
repob(master)>git merge repoa/master
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no "ignore file during merge" directive, but you're already in trouble well before this, at the step *create a GitHub repo that is a copy of [another] repo minus [some] files* because repositories are made of *commits* and commits are immutable. If you take existing commits, remove files from them, and commit the result, you have different commits. If you keep the existing commits, it's not a "copy minus" it's a "copy plus": initially, a copy, then more commits added.

Comment: @torek I reversed the direction to see if that will work.

Comment: That does sound more workable. In all cases you're always adding more commits, but here you'll have an easy time of merging because files that are never in some chain of commits are never touched in the other chain of commits.